# How do you compile a Gradle sub-project using debug classes from another module

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, gradle, multi-project

I am working on the evolution of an Apache Ant project to compile it with Gradle, and I have different set of sub-projects.

My goal is to use the output of the main project as a dependency of some of the subprojects. The global configuration is the following:

```
MainProject:
 -> src/main/java
 -> src/main/resources
 -> src/test/java
 -> src/test/resources
 -> src/mocks/java

ChildProject1:
 -> src/main/java
 -> src/main/resources
 -> src/test/java
 -> src/test/resources
 -> src/mocks/java
```

The main project is correctly included in the child build path and all links are correctly found when it comes to Eclipse linking.

I have included the main project in the `settings.gradle` file for the `ChildProject` and its dependencies in the build:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':MainProject')
}
```

My problem is that the `ChildProject` needs outputs from the mocks/java to compile and though it seems that the Gradle compilation process does include the "default" output that are the main/java files, I get an error message saying that "symbols" from the mocks can not be found.

I had a similar problem with the `MainProject` test java files compilation that required the mocks to be used, it was solved by adding:

```
sourceSets {
    mocks {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/mocks/java'
        }
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    }
    test {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.mocks.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.mocks.output
    }
}
```

The mock source is correctly added to the test classpath.

**How do I tell my `ChilProject` to use the mocks output from `MainProject` to compile its tests?**

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to point you in correct direction. Normally you declare multi-project dependencies in Gradle like so:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':projA')
}
```

This define implicitly says use the `default` artifacts of `projA` as a dependency.

I believe what you want instead is to use the `mock` artifact of your `projA` dependency. The way to do this is:

1. Create a new `jar` task to combine the class files compiled from the `main` and `mock` sourceSet.

   ```
   task mocksJar(type: Jar) {
       classifier 'mocks'
       group 'build'
       from sourceSets.main.output
       from sourceSets.mocks.output
   }
   ```
2. Export the `mock` artifact in `projA` build by creating a new Gradle configuration called `mocks` and assigning the artifact to export:

   ```
   configuration { mocks }
   artifacts.mocks mocksJar
   ```
3. Import the `mocks` configuration in your project that requires `projA` using the extended dependency syntax:

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile project( path:':projA', configuration:'mocks')
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am currently trying to work out my issue starting from your suggestion.
However I am not sure how I should declare the artifact in my main project, I don't get the line "configuration { mocks } for instance as from what I understands the configurations block is here to define the different sourcesets compilation processes..
I never used artifacts in Gradle, and I find the Gradle official docs unclear.
Thanks for your help, looking forward to a next answer!!

Comment: Sorry about the double post, I did add "mocks" into my configuration (though I'm not sure whats this is doing...) and the compilation goes smoothly but I can't figure where the artifact/jar declaration that follows in your exemple should be, could you precise please?

Comment: You can place the 1. section at the end of your main build file. `jarMocks` should be the task that builds the JAR with the mock source code defined in the `mocks` sourceset. Since the mcoks JAR is missing the primary class files, I updated the 2. section answer.

Comment: Hello, At the moment my Configuration snippet is before "CompileJava", "repositories" and "dependencies". If you don't mind getting a bit off the subject, is the build.gradle order important? Not a single tutorial I read mentions a specific organisation for this file...
Thank you for the 2. update, that was the solution I adopted.
My questions may be really basic I am sorry about it... The tasks are quite unclear to me (I blame gradle doc!), should I have something like:
task jarMocks (type :Jar) { from(Sourcesets.mocks.output) {include(-blabla-) } }. If so what has it to do with Artifacts?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that the jar task needs to be manually created for the new sourceSet. Can i have an up-vote now?